# Book - A women sleeps with members of a starship crew to learn their skills

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a Sci-fi book where a woman sleeps with men in order to learn their craft on a spaceship. One example is her sleeping with the crew's sniper to learn everything about sniping from him.  After she learns what she needs, she goes to someone else.  She does not hurt her lovers.

Comment: We need more information. Can you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and edit in answers to those questions into your question? Like, when did you read this? Was it a paperback? A hardback? An EBook? Do you remember how it ended? Were there pictures? What language?

Comment: One other question that occurs to me: Does she "learn their skills" by just using sex to charm these guys into taking the time to teach her all their technical skills, in daily lessons? Or did you mean to imply that she has the power to *telepathically download* data from a guy's brain, but it only works when her body is pressed up against his body all night? The latter was what I first thought when I saw the title said she "sleeps" with them "to learn their skills." As if the sex, or at least the "being in bed together," were Absolutely Necessary for her to learn things quickly and in detail?

Comment: @Lorendiac - I'm intrigued. Incidentally, can you recommend any such stories that fit the plot you just described?

Comment: @Simpleton Not offhand. It wasn't that Raul's question made one specific book pop into my head as a strong candidate; I was just trying to figure out the *implications* of his very brief description of this woman's M.O.

Comment: @Lorendiac My head went to . . . o 0 O (Oh sure! Just like I learned lit, calculus, and history back in high school! Too bad I went to a university with a No Grinding For Grades policy) ;)